# Bind to child component events

Tags: angular, typescript

I have on one component is the "input" and "span":

```
<div class="form-group form-black">
 <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="l_country_id" #l_country_id='ngModel' name="l_country_id" [(ngModel)]="user.l_country_id" required>  
   <span type="submit" class="input-group-addon btn btn-info" (click)="onOpenModule();">Select Country</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on "span" opens a modal window with a list of all countries. By clicking on one of the countries in the list at the bottom of the modal window once is unblocked the "Select" button. Then should work so after pressing the "Select" button the previously selected country should appear in " Input".

Here is the modal window code:

modal.html:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-content table-responsive">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class=" table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th >Country</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr  class="{{selectedCountry == country ? 'active' : ''}}" *ngFor="let country of countries" (click)="updateSelectedCountry(country?.country_id)">
                <td>{{country.name}} </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="submit" (click)="cancel();">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!selectedCountry?.name" (click)="onClick()">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal.ts:

```
...

export class CountryModalComponent  implements ModalComponent<any> {


  countries: Array<Country>;
  selectedCountry = null;

  constructor(
    public dialog: DialogRef<any>,
    public authTokenService: Angular2TokenService, 
    private servCountry: CountryService
  ) { 
    this.countries = new Array<Country>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCountries();
  }

  private loadCountries() {
    this.servCountry.getCountries().subscribe(countries => this.countries = countries);
  }

  cancel(): void {
    this.dialog.close(null);
  }


  updateSelectedCountry(CountryId) {
    this.selectedCountry = this.countries.find(el => {
      return el.country_id === CountryId
    })
  }

}
```

I know it can be done with @Output. But I do not understand how to make the selected item from the list and then clicking on the "Select" button displays this information in the Input.

Comment: use `EventEmitter` so that you can get value from one component to another while `change` event occurs

Comment: @AkhilAravind is there any example? Is it desirable with a similar situation like mine?

Comment: check the documentation, or there are simple examples